# How to Auto increment a column in mysql table through java

Tags: java, mysql

i have table with 2 columns 1.column1 2.column2(its unique)
now through java coding i am inserting data through 2 methods
in the first method i want to insert data ,in this  coumn1 filed should be auto increment(for new user)

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) values(?, ?)";
pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstm.setInt(1, auto_incrmentvalue need to set);
    pstm.setInt(2,column2);
```

in the second method insert data with what i want

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) values(?, ?)";
pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstm.setInt(1, column1);
    pstm.setInt(2,column2);
```

how to set auto increment value in the first method

**NOTE:Here column1 is not a primary key**

Comment: Do you use Spring JdbcTemplate?

Comment: @QuickSilver - no. Did you not read what the bolded part says?

Comment: not using Spring JdbcTemplate only JDBC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table(column1) SELECT MAX(column1)+1 FROM table
```

This one worked for me

Please see [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Your query should be like this,

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) SELECT MAX(column1)+1, 79  FROM table
```

More refined answer:

```
INSERT INTO
     usertable(column1, column2) 
     SELECT CASE COUNT(column1) 
         WHEN 0 THEN 0 
         ELSE MAX(column1) END+1,
     79 FROM usertable
```

This could be a more simple solution:

```
INSERT INTO usertable(column1, column2) 
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(column1)+1,1),79 FROM usertable
```

Comment: i try like this it give error
mysql> insert into userstable(column1, column2) values ((select max(column1) from table)+1, 79);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'userstable' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this once (not tested)

```
INSERT INTO table(column1) SELECT count(column1)+1 FROM table
```

For ex,

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) SELECT count(column1)+1, 79  FROM table
```

Comment: its working fine i have one more doubt suppose we have 9 columns when one column is deleted then again it stores 9 for the column1 or not?

Answer (score -1):

if you want the auto value of column1, don't set it, just let it get a defult value

```
INSERT INTO table (column2) values(?)
```